# passing value to codeigniter pagination

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, pagination, get

i am using codeigniter pagination. i want to pass a value through url to the controller by which i can fetch data based on condition

```
function index($offset) {  
    $type = $_GET['type'];
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'MarketPostingCenter/index';
    $config['per_page'] = 15;
    // $config['total_rows'] = 200;

    if($type=="Agent"){
        $data['market_posts'] = $this->model->getAllMarketPostsOfAgent('market_posting_tbl', $_SESSION['id'],$config['per_page'],$offset);
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->model->getAllMarketPostsOfAgentCount('market_posting_tbl', $_SESSION['id']);

    }elseif($type=="Underwriter"){
        $data['market_posts'] = $this->model->getAllMarketPosts('market_posting_tbl',$_SESSION['id'],$config['per_page'],$offset);
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->model->getAllMarketPostsCount('market_posting_tbl', $_SESSION['id']);
    }

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    // print_r(  $data['market_posts']);

    $data['user'] = $this->model->getUser('profile_tbl', $_SESSION['id']);
    $data['order'] ="";


    $data['states'] = $this->model->getAllStates('states');
    $this->load->view('MarketPostingCenter/marketPostingCenter.php',$data);
}
```

how can i pass "?type=something" through url without affecting the offset value

Answer (score 0):

change your `base_url` config as follows

```
$config['base_url'] = site_url('MarketPostingCenter/index?type='.$type);
```

it will not affect your offset. Others stuff will automatically be appended after it

Comment: but now  url of second page becomes http://localhost/proect/MarketPostingCenter/index?type=Agent/15  @Rejoanul Alam